# React Native "PhaseScriptExecution" error while building the app on macOS

Tags: react-native, macos

I have m1 macbook and installed required dependencies (cocoapods, npx, npm, etc) following the offical React Native guide ([text](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)). I can create the project called "Awesome project" without a problem.
However, when I try to build the app using "npm run ios" command, I get the following error:

```
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution[CPUser]\Generate\Specs /Users/mustafamelihdemircioglu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject2bpalclpgemvzkscdxfeotefnovbs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E00018190.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I also got the same issue, anyone resolved the issue?

Comment: This error is usually occur for me when I update node version. Just delete the `.xcode.env.local` file in your project's `ios` folder and try again.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps somebody; downgrading the node version to v14.21.3 helped me fix this issue. For me, the bash environment should have v14.21.3.

Steps I took (bash terminal):

- brew install node@14
- brew unlink node
- brew link --overwrite node@14
- removed Podfile. lock and deleted pods folder
- removing all DerivedData (Settings/Locations/DerivedData)
- Close Xcode
- cd ios && pod install
- Try building again

PS: I am using nvm zsh for node version 18 for all my react native projects; just version 14 is required in bash env for the Xcode build.